# AWS TargetGroup/LoadBalancer checks vs CodeDeploy deployment group status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Let's assume the following situation.

TargetGroup is checking the http port 80 to verify that a EC2 host is healthy.

CodeDeploy agent executed a sequence like this

1. ApplicationStop SUCCESS (Stopped web engine. Cannot serve port 80)
2. BeforeInstall SUCCESS
3. AfterInstall SUCCESS
4. ApplicationStart SUCCESS (Started web engine. Can serve port 80)
5. ValidateService FAILED (non related to the availability of the port 80)

With this sequence the CodeDeploy deployment is marked as FAILED. What is the target group doing? As it's health check would be successful, it would consider the EC2 host as healthy? But CodeDeploy things it's not.

What is not clear to me is how TargetGroup health checks overlap with CodeDeploy deployment's status on each EC2.

As the documentation mentions that CodeDeploy collaborates with the load balancer to not route traffic, then my question is extended to the load balancer as well.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**After some discussion with @tangerini**:

In [AppSpec 'hooks' Section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) it mentions that e.g. Allow/Block Trafic hooks are available. But also on the same topic it mentions that someone can use them  only with 
- a classic loadbalancer
- a blue/green deployment.

I'm using a ApplicationLoadBalancer and in-place deployments. But from what I've noticed the traffic reaches the ec2 servers during the ValidateService hook.

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy's deployment status depends solely on the success or failure of the lifecyle event hooks being executed on your instances, and does not necessarily follows the TargetGroup health checks. In your example, the ApplicationStart step completed successfully, which will cause it to start succeeding the TargetGroup health check, even though the ValidateService step failed thus causing the deployment to fail.

Ideally, you want the TargetGroup health check status to match the CodeDeploy ValidateService result every time. If the ValidateService step fails, it means your service is not functioning correctly and should be failing the health check. But that depends on the validation that you are doing in your ValidateService step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the concept of alignment between the two validation points. But the documentation of CodeDeploy hooks (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) mentions the concept of allow/disable traffic which implies some sort of connection with the LoadBalancer or the TargetGroup. The allow traffic step happens after the ValidateService hook. What I see matches your explanation but the doc makes me confused.

Comment: I was answering your question assuming that you have no allow/disable traffic hook since you did not specify them in your example. Allow/disable step will bind and unbind your instance to the target group respectively, so the target group health check won't even get performed if your ValidateService fails and AllowTraffic is skipped, since the failed instance is be bound to the target group.

Comment: I didn't because it was my understanding that they are system hooks and you can't implement them. But you two answers point that I might have overlooked something, so I'll take another look and I'm thankful. Any tips on what I probably overlooked would be great.

Comment: In [AppSpec 'hooks' Section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) it mentions that e.g. Allow/BlockTrafic are available only with a classic loadbalancer or with a blue/green deployment. I'm using a ApplicationLoadBalancer and in-place deployments. I'll try and update the original question